# What's the difference between different priced chests?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Around the level there are always some chests to be found, these chest generally cost 25 or 50 gold to open (in the first level anyway, after that prices may vary).
Is it always better to buy a 50 gold chest instead of a 25 gold one (Assuming you have just enough money to open one of them)? Do they contain different items or is the only difference the pricetag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From experience, the Tiny Chests can have any item white and up, while the Bigger Chests start at green, giving only (if only by a bit) more valuable items. Overall, the only difference is that the Bigger Chests do not give white items, which can be good or bad.

EDIT:
Small chests have a chance of giving an Orange (use item) or White item while big chests can not, and only give Green and Red. Small chests can also give a Green or Red item, but have a higher chance of giving an Orange or White item.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the wiki](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Chest), large chests that cost more have more valuable items in them than small chests, which are cheaper.